# Teaching resources post wiki

Tags: discussion, questions

I teach Databases and I take questions from SO as new exam questions.

A sample to illustrate what I'm talking about:

> Read this text and answer questions below:
>
> [Normalization in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565581/normalization-in-sql)
>
> Question:
>
> - Is this a normalization issue?
> - Rewrite create table with right constraints to avoid OP problem.

I would like to make a post that becomes a community wiki for this subject, like [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) (in spite of the obvious differences).

After reading [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), my questions are:

1. Is this a bad idea to post this kind of questions in SO?
2. What is the right way to achieve this avoiding down votes and compliance with [netiquette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiquette)?

Comment: While I think it's a really cool idea to use SO questions as exam questions, I don't think posting *those* on SO really fits the Q&A format, Community Wiki or not. Can you clarify what purpose they would serve?

Comment: Do you award bonus points for leaving snarky comments in lieu of an actual answer? I could really ace that class! :-)

Comment: @CodyGray, You are wellcome to class ... as teacher.

Comment: The way I understand your concept, you are re-inventing SE. Or maybe a beta of databaseSE. Every SE site is ***supposed to be*** what you are proposing, already, or is it not?

Comment: @kris,In your opinion, should be meta instead SO a more suitable choice?

Comment: Can you clarify what the point of this would be? Do you want to use SO to manage your students' feedback, or make the questions available to the world?

Comment: I teach software enginyering, some questions of some of my students exams are are inspired in SO questions (as post sample). The purpose of commutity would be to keep a list of selected SO question that can become exam question (it self or about question as in post sample). In this way, other teachers can use it or other people can read it to learn. This clarify my post?